# Check if Number is multiplied by (Given number) and assign to a variable

Tags: bash

the question is how to do this calculation in bash.

Let's say u have items

```
a=1
b=2
c=3 and so on....
```

If a variable can be multiplied by 2 then add to group: admin
if multiplied by 3 added to the group: users
if not multiplied by any of those add group: others
And maybe one hybrid :
if multiplied by and 3 add group: special users

Any points would be welcomed.
Most specifically how do u make u check if a number is multiplied by a number.
Sorry if it is a nooby question. Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: Are you asking about *divisibility*? Any number can be *multiplied* by another number.

Comment: Yes checking for divisibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if `n` is divisible by `d`, use the `%` operator.

```
if (( n % d == 0 )); then
  ...
fi
```